# Nothing appearing in UITableView cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on an app that needs to display five different images inside of five different tableview cells. This is the storyboard that I have for the cell.

[image]

This is the code I have inside of the tableviewcontroller.

```
    class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
var returnTable = 1
var icons: [String] = ["settings", "calendar", "classes", "envelope", "grades"]




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()






    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.


    return icons.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeScreenCells


    var image : UIImage = UIImage(named: icons[indexPath.row])!
    cell.icon.image = image


    return cell
}
```

I also have a custom class for the tableviewcells. Also, I have the correct reuse identifier for the cell. Still, the image does not appear. Not only does the image not appear, nothing appears. When I change the background, the background does not change in the simulator. This is all I get in the simulator.

[image]

I have the classes linked up correctly for the split view controller. I have no idea why nothing is appearing in the table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set `numberOfSectionsInTableView` to `1`. if your table doesnt contain more then 1 section then remove code. its optional method.

Comment: Does your imageview is connected to IBOutlet. Or there could be the problem with the size of icon imageview, Try to change the background color of UIImageView then check.

Comment: Setting the sections to one makes it so the background will change, but the image still won't display. The icon is 64x64 and so is the image view. I have it connected to an IBOutlet in the cell class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem may be that you have the number of sections set to 0. Either set it to 1, or leave out the block of code completely.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, return 1 in number of sections (or the number of cells you need). And if your custom cell class has a .xib, you also need to register it, sometimes after you init the tableview

```
tableView.registerNib( UINib(nibName: "HomeScreenCells", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```